# Chrome new tab via URL

Tags: google-chrome-extension

One of the things our extension does is changing Chrome's New Tab. In our extension we have an option to disable our New Tab, then it would have returned the original Chrome New Tab.
It was simply pointing to the Chrome New Tab URL instead of to ours (not actually disabling anything).

It was working fine, until recently when Chrome has blocked access to it's New Tab via URL.

We know about the possibility to do Chrome://apps, but it's not the same.

1. Is there a way still to access the Chrome New Tab via URL somehow?
2. If not, is there a way to simply disable our New Tab in the extension and then it would be like our extension is simply not installed..

The reason we need this is because changing the New Tab is just ONE of the many options our extension provides and we don't want users to delete our extension just because they cannot get Chrome new tab...

Thanks